# Where did I go wrong in my evaluation of the integral of cosine squared?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

$$\int{\cos^2(x)}dx$$
Where did I go wrong in my evaluation of this integral?

$$=x\cos^2x - \int-2x\sin(x)\cos(x)\,dx$$
$$=x\cos^2x + \int x\sin(2x)\,dx$$
$$=x\cos^2x + \left(\frac {-x\cos(2x)}2 -\int \frac{-\cos(2x)}2\,dx\right)$$
$$=x\cos^2x + \left(\frac {-x\cos(2x)}2 + \frac 12\cdot\frac{\sin(2x)}2\right)$$
$$x\cos^2x-\frac{x\cos(2x)}2+\frac{\sin(2x)}4 + C$$

And this is clearly wrong, but I don't know where I messed up in my calculations. Would anyone mind correcting me somewhere?

Comment: Try to expand the result.

Comment: If you want to use integration by parts, it is easier to let $u=\cos x$, $dv=\cos x\,dx$. Then you get $I=\sin x\cos x+\int\sin^2 x\,dx$. Replace $\sin^2 x$ by $1-\cos^2 x$.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your answer is perfectly correct, albeit it is given in a more complicated form than necessary. A little simplification (replacing the $\cos 2x$ by $2\cos^2 x-1$) will put it in standard form.

Comment: Thanks very much! I was convinced my answer was wrong because the graph a derivative calculator gave me of my result seemed so insanely different from what it should've been as the integral of cosine squared. Now I know to not inherently trust these things.

Comment: You are welcome. I made another integration by parts suggestion in a comment above.

Answer (score 5):

$$
\int \cos^2 x dx = \int \frac{1 + \cos(2x)}{2}dx = \frac{x}{2} + \frac{\sin(2x)}{4} + C
$$

Comment: Can you not solve it without the transformation to cos(2x)?

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer not sure, still thinking. This way is quick and elegant - one step takes care of the integration

Answer (score 4):

As noted above, your answer is actually correct, you just have a duplication that cancels.

Alternatively, $\int (1-\sin^2x)\,dx = \int\cos^2 x\,dx$

So: $$\int(\cos^2 x + 1 -\sin^2 x)\,dx = 2\int\cos^2x\,dx.$$ 
Now, $\cos^2 x -\sin^2 x = \cos 2x$. So the left hand side is:

$$\int(1+\cos(2x))\,dx = x + \frac{1}{2}\sin(2x) + C$$

Dividing by $2$ and substituting for $\sin(2x)=2\sin x\cos x$, we get:

$$\frac{x+\sin(x)\cos(x)}{2}+C'$$

Answer (score 0):

Using the formula $\displaystyle \bullet \; 2\cos^2 x = 1+\cos 2x$

So $$\displaystyle I = \frac{1}{2}\int 2\cos^2 xdx =\frac{1}{2}\int \left[1+\cos 2x\right]$$

So $$\displaystyle I = \frac{1}{2}\int 1 dx + \frac{1}{2}\int \cos 2x dx = \frac{1}{2}x+\frac{1}{4}\sin 2x+\mathcal{C}$$

Comment: That's certainly another way to get the right answer, but the question was, what is wrong with OPs calculation. OP's "clearly wrong" answer is, in fact, correct.

Answer (score 0):

Notice, 
$$\int \cos^2 x dx=\int \cos x \cos x dx$$
$$=\int \cos x\sqrt{1-\sin ^2 x}dx$$
Let $\sin x=t\implies \cos x dx=dt$
$$\int \sqrt {1-t^2}dt$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\left[t\sqrt {1-t^2}+\sin^{-1}(t)\right]$$ 
$$=\frac{1}{2}\left[\sin x\sqrt {1-sin^2x}+\sin^{-1}(\sin x)\right]$$ 
$$=\frac{1}{2}\left[\sin x\cos x+x\right]+C$$ 
$$=\frac{1}{2}\sin x\cos x+\frac{x}{2}+C$$ 
$$=\frac{x}{2}+\frac{1}{4}\sin2x+C$$

Comment: don't you need a trig substitution for that one :-)?

Comment: No trig substitution, it can be directly solved using product rule

Comment: you can check it there is no trig substitution

Comment: That requires knowing $\int\sqrt{1-t^2}\,dt$, which is not trivial, either. The other solutions, using $\cos 2x$ formula, are much more elementary.

Answer (score 0):

Notice,Let  $$I=\int \cos^2 xdx$$

$$\implies I=\int \cos x\cos xdx$$ $$=\cos x\int \cos x-\int (-\sin x)\sin xdx$$ $$=\cos x(\sin x)+\int \sin^2 xdx$$ $$=\frac{1}{2}(2\sin x \cos x)+\int (1-\cos^2 x)dx$$ $$=\frac{1}{2}\sin 2x+\int dx-\int \cos^2 xdx$$
$$I=\frac{1}{2}\sin 2x+x-I+c$$
$$2I=\frac{1}{2}\sin 2x+x+c$$
$$I=\frac{1}{4}\sin 2x+\frac{x}{2}+C$$